# Identify sender in http module

Tags: c#, ihttpmodule

I am developing a page tracker app where i need the login time,log out time ,session id,logged in user and each page accessed by user,time spent on that page and the list of event's in a page that are fired when controls are clicked,checked or selected.i dont want to use google analytics

For now i am accessing all the details by writing session start etc in http modules and everything is achieved.i am storing all the data in a hashtable and throwing them into db when logout is clicked or session time's out.i am struck on how to identify if logout button is pressed .

i can directely write the piece of code for inserting the statistics on the click of logout button itself but i dont want to do so as i want to capture the logout button id or text in http modules and then write the logic in http module.i tried to capture the sender but it's throwing an error by referring the asax reference instead of button reference

how can i acheieve this(track which button is clicked on a page and get the id in http module because the http module triggers for every postback or load)?

Comment: Any particular reason for not using events?

Comment: i am writing the event's in http module but i am not using global.asax.the reason i am not writing in button click is if i have like 100 application i can't go and write the code the button clicks.if i write in the httpmodule i just register the http module in web.config.a single line of code is enough

Answer (score 0):

You could use your `HttpContext.Request.Form` object. It contains Key "__EVENTTARGET", which value equals to ID of object that sends POST to Server.